# How to pick an amended commit from another branch

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, say "branch_1" and "branch_2" like so:

```
A <--master
\
 B <--branch_1
  \
   C <--branch_2
```

Now I make a change in branch_1 and amend the HEAD commit. So now the setup looks like:

```
A <--master
|\
| B_amended <--branch_1
|  
B---C <--branch_2
```

A git log on branch_1 shows commit B_amended on top of HEAD commit of A. A git log on branch_2 shows commit B and C on top of HEAD commit of A. Commit B on branch_2 does not contain amended changes of commit B_amended on branch_1.

My question is: how do I bring B_amended into branch_2 to make it look like this?

```
A <--master
\
 B_amended <--branch_1
  \
   C <--branch_2
```

Right now I am doing:

```
$ git checkout branch_2
$ git reset --soft HEAD~
$ git stash
$ git rebase branch_1
$ git stash apply
$ git commit
```

Is there a better method?

Comment: When you amended `B` did it not amend it for any branch having it in its history?  In other words, is your question really necessary?

Comment: I don't understand your diagrams.  Why are there multiple `A`s and `B`s?  Also, after amending `B` (actually creating a new `B_amended`), `C` does not magically get `B_amended` as a parent.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Yea, I saw that, and just assumed that was a mistake and B hung off A and C off B.

Comment: @Svante If HEAD of master is A and I branch "branch_1" from master, "branch_1" starts with A at head. Similarly when I branch "branch_2" from "branch_1", "branch_2" starts with B at head. Hence there are multiple A's and B's.

Comment: @Tim, after amending B in "branch_1" and then checking out "branch_2" does not show B_amended so I am assuming that the change in B_amended is absent too.

Comment: @DavidN Your assumption is right

Comment: @SachinSharma: I think that it would improve the readability of your diagrams if the _same thing_ did not appear in two places.  Note that in git, a branch is just an "auto-updating tag" pointing at one commit.

Comment: @Svante Done. Question edited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did find a better method: Do an interactive rebase and delete commit "B" from "branch_2".

So after "B_amended" in "branch_1", do the following:

```
$ git checkout branch_2
$ git rebase branch_1 -i
```

In the editor that pops up, **delete** the line that says the equivalent of:

```
pick B
```

Save and exit

Doing so will essentially replay just "C" on top of "B_amended".

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can just checkout branch_1 and git cherry-pick branch_2, which will pull that C commit onto the tip of your branch_1 and `git reset --soft branch_2` to put branch_2 onto that latest commit.

You can also do a rebase (which is probably more straight forward), `git rebase --onto branch_1 branch_2~1 branch_2`

From git merge --help:

```
First let's assume your topic is based on branch next. For example, a feature developed in topic depends on
   some functionality which is found in next.

           o---o---o---o---o  master
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   o---o---o  topic


We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on which topic
   depends was merged into the more stable master branch. We want our tree to look like this:

           o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             o'--o'--o'  topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next

   We can get this using the following command:

       git rebase --onto master next topic

   Another example of --onto option is to rebase part of a branch. If we have the following situation:

                                   H---I---J topicB
                                  /
                         E---F---G  topicA
                        /
           A---B---C---D  master

   then the command

       git rebase --onto master topicA topicB

   would result in:

                        H'--I'--J'  topicB
                       /
                       | E---F---G  topicA
                       |/
           A---B---C---D  master

   This is useful when topicB does not depend on topicA.
```